# IOS-Book-Article.cls: one author with multiple affiliation

Tags: article, affiliation

I'm trying to set for an article the authors information. There is one author that has multiple affiliation and I have some difficulties to write the right code for that. Thank you in advance for any help.

> As error message I'm getting this ! Undefined control sequence.
>    \fnms {John} \snm {Marc}

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{IOS-Book-Article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined,algo2e]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{multicol}

%\usepackage{times}
%\normalfont
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[mtplusscr,mtbold]{mathtime}
%

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}


\pagestyle{headings}
\def\thepage{}

\begin{frontmatter}              % The preamble begins here.


%\pretitle{Pretitle}
\title{Some definitions}

%\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[1,2,a]{\fnms{John} \snm{Marc}}%
%\thanks{Corresponding Author: Book Production Manager, IOS Press, Nieuwe Hemweg 6B,
%1013 BG Amsterdam, The Netherlands; E-mail:
%bookproduction@iospress.nl.}},
and
\author[1,b]{\fnms{Peter} \snm{Wolf}}
and
\author[1,c]{\fnms{Dean} \snm{Boy}}

%\runningauthor{B.P. Manager et al.}
\affiliation[A]{University of LATEX, Higher Institute lab}
\affiliation[B]{niversity of LATEX, Math lab}

\end{document}
```

[image]    \tt{(a)email1@gmail.com,(b)email2@gmail.com,(c)email3@yahoo.com}

At bottom is an image showing what I want to reproduce. [Here is the IOS-Book-Article class file](http://www.texpaste.com/n/9z0o12tq) used in the article code.

Comment: I have tried the following code but it gives no author name nor author affiliation output:

    \author[John Marc]%
      {John Marc\textsuperscript{1,2}, Peter Wolf\textsuperscript{1}, Dean Boy$^1$
    \\
    $^1$University of LATEX, Higher Institute lab\\
    $^2$University of LATEX, Math lab}

Comment: If you have to use that class, it's obviously wrong to load `authblk`. Where can the instructions for the class be retrieved?

Comment: Egreg class instructions can be found here: http://www.texpaste.com/n/9z0o12tq

Comment: No, those aren't instructions

Comment: Instructions can be downloaded from here: http://www.iospress.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ECRC-Author-Instructions-and-tools-LaTeX.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the class doesn't provide for double affiliations of a single author. If you are required to use the class, don't try tweaking its internals, because this will only annoy the copy editors and may cause rejection of your paper.

A double affiliation is quite simple to achieve, though.

```
\documentclass{IOS-Book-Article}

\begin{document}


\begin{frontmatter}              % The preamble begins here.

\title{Some definitions}

\author[A]{\fnms{John} \snm{Marc}}%
\thanks{Corresponding Author: Book Production Manager, IOS Press, Nieuwe Hemweg 6B,
1013 BG Amsterdam, The Netherlands; E-mail:
bookproduction@iospress.nl.},
and
\author[C]{\fnms{Peter} \snm{Wolf}}
and
\author[C]{\fnms{Dean} \snm{Boy}}

\address[A]{University of \LaTeX, Higher Institute lab\\
and University of \LaTeX, Math lab}
\address[C]{Some University}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To whom it can help. I sligthly modified Egreg solution to add emails in titles.

```
\documentclass{IOS-Book-Article}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}              % The preamble begins here.

\title{Some definitions}
\author[A,B,C]{\fnms{John} \snm{Marc}}%
,
\author[B,D]{\fnms{Peter} \snm{Wolf}}
,
\author[B,E]{\fnms{Dean} \snm{Boy}}

\address[A]{University of \LaTeX, Higher Institute lab}
\address[B]{Some University}


\address[C]{\tt{johnmarc@gmail.com}}
\address[D]{\tt{peterwolf@gmail.com}}
\address[E]{\tt{deanboy@gmail.com}}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```